# How can I keep from iterating this collection twice?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

**NOTE:** I've changed the names of the collections because of confidentiality.

Consider the following code:

```
o.Flag =
    o2.Collection1
        .Any(cpd => cpd.Collection1
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag))) ||
    o2.Collection1
        .Any(cpd => cpd.Collection2
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)));
```

Clearly what I'm doing is flattening the detailed flags into an overall flag, but this code as is iterates `o2.Collection1` twice.

I don't see how `SelectMany` can do the job because the flags are on two different collections (i.e. I'm not flattening a collection of collections).

How can I keep from doing that?

**NOTE:** I feel like Jon Skeet, when I read this post ([Using LINQ to flatten a hierarchical dataset - with a caveat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5858608/using-linq-to-flatten-a-hierarchical-dataset-with-a-caveat)) was basically saying I'm stuck. But hopefully I'm reading it wrong!

Comment: Can't you just `var col = o2.Collection1.ToArray(); // Same LINQ query you have, but based on col`?

Comment: Those seem to be exactly identical?

Comment: What is the difference between those two, they seem same

Comment: You aren't stuck; you aren't doing unlimited recursion.  Just move the `||` into the `Any()`.

Comment: @Habib, I'm sorry. When confidentialityizing the code I messed up the `||`.

Comment: Assuming this is a case of a typo, you *can* use `SelectMany` to flatten up until the second last layer (PLCs), then iterate twice over each collection for the `Any`s.

Comment: Are both collections the same type?

Comment: Keep in mind that iterating a collection twice, or iterating it once but doing twice as much work per iteration, is doing the same amount of work.  The main compelling reason to avoid iterating an iterable object more than once is in cases where it may not yield the same information each time it's iterated, cases where iteration causes side effects, or in cases where it represents something that takes a lot of effort to compute, like a DB query.  Iterating a collection has none of those problems.

Comment: @Magus, the collections `cpd => cpd.Collection1` and `cpd => cpd.Collection2` eventually lead to the same type at the leaf, but they are truly different collections.

Comment: That's fine, I was just asking whether or not you can `.Zip` them. Servy did it better though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the collections are of the same type (or have a common base type defining sufficient information) you can simply concat them in your query:

```
o.Flag =
    o2.Collection1
        .Any(cpd => cpd.Collection1.Concat(cpd.Collection2)
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)));
```

Note that the primary advantage here is simply making a simpler query, and reducing code duplication.  It's not going to have any noticeable effect on how well it performs [as long as your collection is actually an in memory collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208697/how-can-i-keep-from-iterating-this-collection-twice/24208844#comment37378491_24208697)

If they are not of compatible types (or there are subtle differences in the predicates for each sub-collection, unlike the example given), then the best that you can manage is to pull both sub-queries into the predicate of the main collection:

```
o.Flag =
    o2.Collection1
        .Any(cpd => cpd.Collection1
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)) ||
            cpd.Collection2
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)));
```

Comment: So if I understand your comment above, you're saying that because I'm concatenating the lower collections together I'm really not doing any more work? Well, let me clarify that, I am in fact iterating the root collection twice with the way I had it, but it's not producing a noticeable difference when issuing the `Concat` with the new way, right?

Comment: It's still *possibly* safer, with the caveats explained in the comments on your question, but the main thing is that the code is simpler. That's worth it even if the performance is unchanged.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud The point is that aside from any marginal overhead from resetting the counter etc. there is no performance difference between iterating twice and doing half your work on each pass, or iterating once and doing all the work in one pass.

Comment: @Magus Yes, it's absolutely worth it, I just think that it's worth calling out what you get.  You're doing this solely for the readability improvements, not for any change in performance, given that the caveats mentioned don't appear to apply.  The second solution addresses those caveats, but doesn't (noticeably) improve readability.

Comment: This would, however, have a significant performance effect if `o2.Collection1` is some sort of lazy enumerable where the items are reified only as you iterate. Eg. a LINQ to SQL query or something.

Comment: @Asad Which I mentioned in the comment to the question that I linked to in the answer.  But yes, that is an important consideration to make.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a single iteration up till the first layer, then branch into two separate queries.

```
o.Flag =
    o2.Collection1
        .Any(cpd => cpd.Collection1
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)) || 
             cpd.Collection2
            .Any(plc => plc.Collection1
                .Any(vd => vd.DetailedFlag)));
```